# Proof in Spivak's Calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

I'm working through Spivak's Calculus, and am trying to show that the following is true:

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x} \to f( c \cdot x ) = f(x) \text{ for all } c \in \mathbb{R}
$$

The book just says:

$f( c \cdot 0 ) = f( 0 )$ for all $c$. QED

which I find kind of lame.

Can anyone fill me in here? I feel like Spivak has left some of the explaining out.

What am I missing?

Comment: $f(2)=1/(1+2)\neq f(1)=1/(1+1)$

Comment: What is $IR$? Do you mean $I \setminus R$, or something else?

Comment: AS MryouthMath's example shows, maybe some assumptions are lacking.

Comment: @jdods - It's the LaTeX I found online for the set of all real numbers.

Comment: Do you mean this: $c\in\mathbb{R}$? Typeset it this way: \$c\in\mathbb{R}\$.

Comment: Ah, cool. I assumed that package isn't available. I'll update the question.

Comment: It looks like you are in Chapter 3 #1 vi) For which numbers $c$ is there a number $x$ such that $f (cx) = f (x)$. If so, then you have the questions misundertstood.

Comment: So, when he says "a number x" he is limiting x to literally one real number and not the entire set $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: See my answer below. The question is "for which numbers $c$, is there a number $x$, such that $f(cx)=f(x)$?" So you fix $c$ first, then look for an $x$ that satisfies $f(cx)=f(x)$.

Comment: In the answer below ( thanks, btw ), it looks like x was fixed first. Is that wrong?

Comment: I see: the wording of the question is meant to say, "Fix c to $\mathbb{R}$. Then, find the domain of x so that the statement is true"?

Comment: @StudentsTea : Perhaps you mean "Fix $c$ _in_ $\mathbb R$"?  At any rate, it is not asking for which values of $x$ this is true, with $c$ fixed.  Rather it is asking for which numbers $c$ is there _at least one_ number $x$ for which this is true. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

You have misunderstood the question.

Spivak's Calculus, third edition, page 48, problem 1 from chapter 3:

1. Let $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x}.$

...

(vi) For which numbers $c$ is there a number $x$ such that $f (cx) = f (x)$.
Hint: There are a lot more than you might think at first glance.

Answer:
(vi) $f(cx)=f(x)$ means that $\frac{1}{1+cx}=\frac{1}{1+x} \ \Rightarrow \ cx=x.$

If $x=0$, then $c$ can be any real number. Thus we conclude that for any $c$, there is at least one $x$ such that $f(cx)=f(x)$, namely, $x=0$.

Comment: The $\Rightarrow$ should be a $\iff$, else you're not proving anything.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't take into account everything that the problem said.  The problem says:

"For which numbers $c$ is there a number $x$ such that $f(cx) = f(x)$." (It actually has a full stop rather than a question mark.  A typo.)

Where you found "for all $c=\mathbb R$" is not clear. (I'm guessing you meant "for all $c\in\mathbb R$".)

It doesn't say "for all $x$" but rather "is there a number $x$".  That's exactly the kind of thing that you need to focus on on in a problem like this.

Some simple algebra reduces the question to this: For which numbers $c$ is there a number $x$ such that $cx=x$?  If $c$ is any number at all, then this equality holds when $x=0$.  So the answer is: for **every** number $c$ there is a number $x$ such that $f(cx) = f(x)$.

Comment: The chapter said when the domain or range of a function isn't specified, it is assumed that either ( or both ) is $\mathbb{R}$. The domain of c isn't specified. So, until we rule out some elements in $\mathbb{R}$, $c = \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @StudentsTea : You are confusing $c\in\mathbb R$ with $c=\mathbb R$. The latter means $c$ _is_ the set of all real numbers, the former means $c$ is _in_ the set of all real numbers.  There is no "domain of$\text{ }c$", since $c$ is a number, not a function. And $c$ is is indeed specified where it says "For which numbers $c$[?]".  That means "For which numbers $c\in\mathbb R$?"  You clearly misunderstood the statement about the specification of the domain or range of a function. $\qquad$